# using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to find <img> and height

Tags: php

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to return multiple images from external pages. I need to minimize the amount of images that are returned by only returning images with a width greater than 50px and a height greater that 60px.

How can I use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to pull the height and width of each image as it runs and only returning the images that meet the requirements above?

Thanks!

EDIT added code

So far, this is what I have.

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $images = $element->src;
    echo $images;
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Did you read the manual and example code on their site?

Comment: Added the code block above. Yes, I've read the manual on their site.

Comment: @Paul hi, what solution did you find for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the height isn't specified as an attribute in the HTML, you'll have to make HTTP requests to download each image to do so.

Fortunately PHP [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) supports URLs:

```
$images = /* code to find images in the DOM */;
$res = array();
foreach ($images AS $img) {
    $res[$img] = getimagesize($img);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for the reply. However, getimagesize() is VERY slow when used this way. It's okay if the some of the images are lost due to missing height

Comment: It's slow because it's making HTTP requests to the remote server to retrieve the image - can't be avoided. There's simply no other way to find the dimensions without 1) having a hint in the HTML or 2) fetching the image.

Comment: Isn't the height="x" attribute a good indicator when associated with an <img> tag? I understand height may not always exist, and that's ok for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: One of the two dimensions satisfying your minimum requirement doesn't means the other will, but if you run a small test & check the % this happens you can determine if the range is acceptable in your use case. Otherwise, IMO, it's relatively safe to assume that at dimensions of 50-60px that if one is greater than that the other will be too, and visa-versa in terms of smaller than.

Comment: @paul, far too often sites use high-res images even on thumbs, (you'll notice them load slowly). attr height by no means indicate true height of image.

Comment: @user, and thats ok. I'm just trying to weed out the 1px x 1px images, and other small graphics. I'm after the larger ones.